# How can I list VIs in order from simplest (that only uses built-in functions) to the most complex in LabVIEW?

Tags: dependencies, vi, labview

I inherited a project with multiple VIs and have no idea where to start to clean it up or just understand it. Is there a way to list the VIs in order of their degree of dependency on other VIs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Menu: View->VI Hierarchy. [LabVIEW docs](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361J-01/lvdialog/hierarchy_window/)